# Length of matched Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

"abc def" should match the following regex because "abc" and "def" both have 3 characters

```
/([a-z]*) ([a-z]*){\1.length}/
```

Is there a way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: Does it have to be a regex solution?

Comment: @Mark Yes, that would preferable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of strings you describe do not form a regular language. It cannot be matched by a regular expression. It's one of the classic examples of languages that can't be matched with a regular expression (another is testing for matching parentheses).

Just compare the lengths of the two strings in ordinary code.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, \1 and \2 should correspond to "abc" and "def". Can I still use these variables outside the regular expression?

Comment: Regular expressions haven't been regular for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

No, not with regex alone. The part: `{\1.length}` is not valid, at least, not as you're hoping to use it.

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
if /([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)/ =~ 'abc def' and $1.length == $2.length
  print 'OK'
else
  print 'No match...'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def match_equal_length(s, regex)
  m = s.scan(r)
  return m[0] if (m.size > 0) && (m[0][0].size == m[0][1].size)
  nil # String doesn't match or $1.size != $2.size
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in the regex but you can get pretty close by using a block with [`match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-i-match):

```
two_same_length = s.match(/([a-z]*) ([a-z]*)/) { |m| m[1].length == m[2].length }
```

The whole match is in [`m[0]` in the block](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html), you want to look at the groups so you want `m[1]` and `m[2]`. If you always want a boolean (instead of a `nil` if there is no match at all) then double-bang it:

```
two_same_length = !!s.match(/([a-z]*) ([a-z]*)/) { |m| m[1].length == m[2].length }
```

For example:

```
>> !!'abc pancakes'.match(/([a-z]*) ([a-z]*)/) { |m| m[1].length == m[2].length }
=> false
>> !!'pancakes'.match(/([a-z]*) ([a-z]*)/) { |m| m[1].length == m[2].length }
=> false
>> !!'whereis pancake'.match(/([a-z]*) ([a-z]*)/) { |m| m[1].length == m[2].length }
=> true
```